# Flutter bangla font not supported, getting from apis, showing only symbols of bangla font

Tags: android, flutter, api

I am not able to parse bangla font , called api for getting content , where some of bangla content, but not getting bangla, showing some symbolse, how i get rid of this ? symbols like "¦®à¦¾à¦²à¦¿à¦à¦¾à¦¨à¦¾à¦§à§à¦¨, à¦¯à¦¾à¦° à¦¨à¦¿à¦¬à¦¨à§à¦§à¦¿à¦¤ à¦à¦«à¦¿à¦¸
à¦¹à¦¾à¦à¦¸: à§¨à§¬à§ª/à¦¬à¦¿, à¦ªà¦¶à§à¦à¦¿à¦® à¦®à¦¾à¦¨à¦¿à¦à¦¦à§, à¦¢à¦¾à¦à¦¾ à¦à§à¦¯à¦¾à¦¨à§à¦à¦¨à¦®à§à¦¨à§à¦,
à¦¢à¦¾à¦à¦¾-à§§à§¨à§¦à§¬ (à¦¨à¦¿à¦¬à¦¨à§à¦§à¦¨ à¦¨à¦®à§à¦¬à¦°: à§§à§®à§©à§¬à§«à§©) à¦ à¦à¦¬à¦¸à§à¦¥à¦¿à¦¤à¥¤ à¦à¦®à¦¾à¦¦à§à¦° à¦-à¦à¦®à¦¾à¦°à§à¦¸ à¦ªà§à¦°à§à¦à¦¾à¦²à§à¦° à¦à¦¯à¦¼à§à¦¬à¦¸à¦¾à¦"

i tried, but not able to get rid of,

Comment: Share your code which you are trying with details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, using the utf8 decoder, like regular decode json.decode()
`json.decode(utf8.decode(result.bodyBytes));` solved this problem